# HTML 5 fortune wheel (lunchwheel)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a simple fortune wheel implementation form [here](http://bramp.net/blog/2011/07/27/html5-canvas-lunch-wheel/),  using HTML 5 , but I'm having some issue in finding the winner segment , here is the code in JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/bramp/94jP6/

Important functions in JSFiddle :

```
// Called when segments have changed
update: function() {
    // Ensure we start mid way on a item
    //var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheel.segments.length);
    var r = 0;
    wheel.angleCurrent = ((r + 0.5) / wheel.segments.length) * Math.PI * 2;

    var segments = wheel.segments;
    var len = segments.length;
    var colors = wheel.colors;
    var colorLen = colors.length;

    // Generate a color cache (so we have consistant coloring)
    var seg_color = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    seg_color.push(colors[segments[i].hashCode().mod(colorLen)]);

    wheel.seg_color = seg_color;

    wheel.draw();
}
```

and

```
drawNeedle: function() {
    var ctx = wheel.canvasContext;
    var centerX = wheel.centerX;
    var centerY = wheel.centerY;
    var size = wheel.size;

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fileStyle = '#ffffff';

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(centerX + size - 40, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + size + 20, centerY - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + size + 20, centerY + 10);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    // Which segment is being pointed to?
    var i = wheel.segments.length - Math.floor((wheel.angleCurrent / (Math.PI * 2)) * wheel.segments.length) - 1;

    // Now draw the winning name
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.font = "2em Arial";
    ctx.fillText(wheel.segments[i], centerX + size + 25, centerY);
},
```

in line 256 is where the current code is getting the winner :

```
var i = wheel.segments.length - Math.floor((wheel.angleCurrent / (Math.PI * 2)) * wheel.segments.length) - 1;
```

but thats on the right side of the wheel , Im trying to make it get the segment on top as the winner point . I have been struggling with it for a long time and i appreciate your help or guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here is a working solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94jP6/247/)** . And the explanation is below:

First we need to draw the pointer to the correct position, on top of the wheel:

```
drawNeedle: function() {
    ...
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX + 20, centerY - size - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX - 20, centerY - size - 20);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX  , centerY - size + 20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ...
}
```

In the code segment here that you have given:

```
var i = wheel.segments.length - Math.floor((wheel.angleCurrent / (Math.PI * 2)) * wheel.segments.length) - 1;
```

The `wheel.angleCurrent / (Math.PI * 2)` part means that it is on the right side. Note that in JavaScript that is where we start for a "unit circle". To fix this we just need to off-set the angle by 90 degrees (or in our case add `Math.PI/2` in radians):

```
    var change = wheel.angleCurrent + (Math.PI/2);
    var i = wheel.segments.length - Math.floor((change / ( Math.PI * 2)) * wheel.segments.length) - 1;
    if(i < 0) i = i + 17; // 17 = wheel.segments.length
```

The way `i` is calculated is depended on that we start on the right. It offsets by a few items when we change it going from `-5 to 12` other than `0 to 16`. To fix that on negative items (our offset items) we just need to add them be our 13 to 16. In other-words add 17 (which is the same as `wheel.segments.length`).

Comment: You are superb, :) i guess i would have been struggling with it for ages. Thanks a lot.